# Java object to IOS NSDictionary, property order

Tags: java, ios, json, spring

I am a `Java` developer working on an `iOS` application which sends requests to a `Java Spring` backend on the server.

When a call is made, the backend returns a JSON to frontend where it is deserialized into an `NsDictionary`, and it works fine.

However, now the client has asked that the fields on the front end be sorted in an order he had given us.

I have tried to annotate the object like so:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"firstName","lastName","mobile","email",  "address","city","state","gender"})
public final class User{ ... }
```

But while that sorts the properties in the string representation, when it is deserialized into an `NsDictionary`, it is instead ordered alphabetically by its fields.

Can this sorting be done, and how can we implement it?

Best regards, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary doesn't support a certain order for keys, and the alphabetical order is just how it presents the string representation, internally they have no order.

You can try to alter your data model to include a sortIndex property, like

```
{"firstName":{sortIndex:0,value:"John"}}
```

Or easier, you can put each key value pair as an entry in an array, like

```
[{"firstName":"John"},{"lastName":"Doe"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andrei

I took your second solution and this is what i have done and what works for me :

1) I have ordered the fields in the class the way the client wanted.

2) I have added the following method to class :

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
List<HashMap<String,String>> keyValues = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
public List<HashMap<String, String>> getKeyValues() {
    return keyValues;
}
public void initKeyValuePairs(){
    Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for( int i=0 ; i<19 ; i++ ){
        try {
            HashMap<String,String> pom = null;
            if(fields[i].get(this)!=null){
                pom = new HashMap<String,String>();
                pom.put(fields[i].getName(), fields[i].get(this).toString());
                keyValues.add(pom);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

Thus, now when i fully populate the User model, i just invoke this method and the JSON returns an array of Objects, properly sorted.

(PS : There are more than 19 fields in my class, but the client asked that the first 19 be as he had stated, so i just take the first 19 and ignore the rest. :) )

Thanks for the help.